# Dart Debugger Not Stopping at Break Points

Tags: debugging, dart

I have breakpoints in my code.  I launch my app from the Dart Editor.  My app runs in Dartium.  But when I exercise my app, none of the break points are hit.

The Dart Editor shows that the debugger is running (Debug tabbed window with red Terminate button).

How can I make Dart script execution stop at breakpoints using the Dart Editor and Dartium?

Details about the tools I'm using:

- Dart Editor and SDK 0.6.21_r26639
- Dartium/Chromuim (bundled with SDK/Editor) version 30.0.1599.0 (217147).
- Mint Linux 15 (based on Ubuntu 13.04) 64 bit.

Comment: I relaunched IDE. I hope it will helps for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this behavior is (relatively) consistent for either of you, can you try something out? See if you have any chrome extensions installed in Dartium and disable them. There are some extensions that will effectively disable our ability to debug code and hit breakpoints. They generally have a similar behavior on the devtools debugger as well however.

Comment: Thank you. You nailed it.  A Chrome extension caused the Dartium debugger to not work.  It was the LastPass extension.  I never installed it in Dartium, but it was installed for my Chrome browser.  It would be nice if Dartium showed a warning (at least once) saying that extensions may break the debugger.  I'm happy I can now use Dart's debugger!  Thanks again.